# React Native Flatlist dynamic style

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make buttons out of react native FlatList items, that means when I click on them they change color.
This is the function that gets rendered by the renderItem prop:

```
renderRows(item, index) {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    key={index}
    style={[styles.item, this.calculatedSize()]}
    onPress={() => this.onPressImage(index)}
  >
    <Image
      style={[styles.picture]}
      source={{ uri: item.uri }}
    />
    <View
      style={[
        styles.imageTextContainer,
        {
          backgroundColor:
            _.indexOf(this.active, index) === -1
              ? 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
              : 'rgba(26, 211, 132, 0.7)',
        },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.imageText}>{item.title}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 )
}
```

oh yeah and im using loadash to get the index.
The function "onPressImage(index)" works fine, in "this.active" (array) I always have the positions(integer) of the elements I would like to change color,
however nothing happens, the only thing you can see is the response by the touchableOpacity. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You’re affecting how something looks you will need to update state as that will trigger a re-render. So It may be better to store the array of active values in state.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5508175/andrew) said, you need to trigger a re-render, usually by updating state.

However, if the items don't depend on anything outside the FlatList, I would recommend creating a component (preferably a PureComponent if possible) for the items themselves, and updating their state upon press. This way it will only re-render each list item individually if there is a change instead of the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, updating the state was a little bit difficult, the items array I've used has been declared outside the class component, thus only using an "active" array with indices that should change color in the state wasn't enough, I had to map the items array in the state like so:

```
state = {
  items: items.map(e => ({
    ...e,
    active: false,
  }))
}
```

then I could manipulate the active state of the element I wanted to change color like this:

```
onPressItem(index) {
  const { items } = this.state
  const newItems = [...this.state.items]
  if (items[index].active) {
    newItems[index].active = false
  } else {
    newItems[index].active = true
  }
  this.setState({ items: newItems })
}
```

and change the color like so:

```
style={{
  backgroundColor: item.active
    ? 'rgba(26, 211, 132, 0.7)'
    : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
}}
```